# have ui.item.index() ignore clsss

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table I'm using jquery Ui sortable.
in the table I have nested rows with different class names.
How I can have ui.item.index()  dont count the rows that has that class name when I position an element on the table.

```
$(".slds-card .slds-card__body table tbody").sortable({
      axis: "y",
      cancel: '.functionClass' 
  }).disableSelection()
    .on("sortstart", function(event, ui) {
            initialPos = ui.item.index();
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to exclude a row with a specific class...

```
$(".slds-card .slds-card__body table tbody").sortable({
      axis: "y",
      cancel: '.functionClass' 
  }).disableSelection()
    .on("sortstart", function(event, ui) {
            if( !ui.item.hasClass('exclude') ) {
               initialPos = ui.item.index();
            }
      })
```